# sqlite: insert a row using sqlite_sequence record

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in my database... I want to insert a row to `table1` by reading from a record on `sqlite_sequence`... I know the `sqlite_sequence` table is for AUTOINCREMENT... and also my `table1` has AUTOINCREMENT for `_id` as well... 
I tried this:

```
 INSERT INTO table1 (column_1, column_2) VALUES ((SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name=other_table),`other_column`);
```

but after inserting, inserted row will be deleted in `table1`...
I want to know the last row id in `other_table`... and i tried with `last_insert_rowid()` instead of `(SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name=other_table)`... but the result was same...
Where is my mistake?? thanks!

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: I want to know last row id on `other_table`... i think maybe the `sqlite_sequence` table is created for this purpose...

Comment: I think you are better off using something like `select max(rowid) from other_table`

Comment: @Karakuri  like this:  `SELECT max(rowid) FROM other_table`??... capital is important?

Comment: In my experience with SQLite, case doesn't matter

Comment: i tried!...same result!

Comment: @Karakuri  this is the result after that command : `Error: near "SELECT": syntax error`

Comment: What do you mean with "row will be deleted"? Is there some error? Did you forget to commit a transaction?

Comment: make sure the query is surrounded by parentheses: `insert into table (column) values ((select max(rowid) from other_table));`

Comment: @Karakuri thanks... it works now!